# Nginx 502 with JS window location href

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, window.location

I have a nodeJS app which run with pm2 on port 8080 and I use Nginx to proxy the request from port 80 to port 8080.
Everything works fine until I redirect in Javascript with window.location.href to one of my php file.
I got Nginx 502 status Bad gateway.
**But when I refresh my page on which I have my Nginx error, the error disappear and I get my page**.
My Nginx configuration is very simple.

```
server {
    server_name myDomainName;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}
```

And here is my NodeJS server.

```
var path = require("path");
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs'); 
const express = require("express");
const compression = require('compression');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors"); 
var phpExpress = require("php-express")({
  binPath: "php",
});
require('dotenv').config()

// express settings 
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(`${path.resolve(__dirname, '..')}/frontend/public`));
app.use('/documents',express.static(`${path.resolve(__dirname, '..')}/backend/documents`));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(compression());

// php settings
app.set("views", `${path.resolve(__dirname, '..')}/frontend/views`);
app.engine("php", phpExpress.engine);
app.set("view engine", "php");
app.all(/.+.php$/, phpExpress.router);

// Root route 
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  if(req.session.isAuthenticated){
    res.redirect("index.php");
  }else{
    res.redirect("login.php");
  }
});

require("./routes/auth.routes.js")(app);


// Listen func
const PORT = 8080;

http.createServer(app).listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on port " + PORT);
});
```

And here is my JS file where I do my redirection.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/auth/register",
   method: "POST",
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   data: formData,
   success: function(res){
     if(res.success == 1){
        // window.location.href = window.location.origin+'/register-success.php'
        window.location.href = 'register-success.php'
     }
     else if(res.success === 0){
        $('.error_register').removeClass('d-none')
     }
   }
})
```

Comment: Ohh god, why?! PHP inside node.js... If you really need both (not sure why tho) let nginx handle php requests. Why mix node & php? All you do in node.js can be easy done just via nginx. BTW: The last commit for "php-express" is over 7 years old. I would say the project is dead and should not be used in production anymore.

Comment: I also change my file to html but it's the same, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with "/" as like below

```
window.location.href = '/register-success.php'
```

Comment: No it's not working I always get 502 bad gateway

Comment: is index.php and login.php pages are working? only register-success.php is not working am i correct? 
1. check in the folder /frontend/views whether the file register-success.php is present with exact name.
2. did you tried pm2 restart after the node code changes and build

Comment: Yes all files working even the register-success.php when I put the url directly in the browser.   
The file register-success.php is obviously present in /fronted/views.
I already tried to restart pm2 but it's always not working.

Comment: check pm2 logs in the terminal. may be during /auth/register POST call some exception causes node server restart and when you redirect to register-success.php that time pm2 might not able to serve the request. Just an assumption but not sure about what is the exact issue.

Comment: you were right. The problem was the PM2. When I submited the form I submited it with file that I store in my server and PM2 was restarting and and therefore the server was no longer accessible. The solution is either not not be on watch mode or to ignore files in a file like ecosystem.config.js.